# Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I imported an Maven application for the Intellij Idea. After configure Spring and Hibernate, i tried to build it. But, Maven return an error to me, the error is:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.571 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-04T15:49:48-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/211M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project GECi: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

If you can help me, i'll appreciate that :D Thanks

Comment: How did you try to build it? Using the IDE? What does the command line "mvn clean install" (without the quotes) print?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `mvn deploy` means you want to deploy to a Maven repository. You need to specify that repository in the `<distributionManagement>` element of the POM.

Comment: And how a do that? I'm sorry, i'm new with that :/